You must specify "rootDirectory" or "shortcuts", but not both
I am using Dart/Flutter on Windows.
I am using File System Picker and File Picker Windows.
I need to select a folder and return the folder full path.
My steps are:

Ask a user to select a folder
I get the popup to select a folder
The problem is that the folder path variable is still null after the folder selection.

Plus, If I don't select a folder and click Cancel on the folder selection popup, then I get this error: You must specify "rootDirectory" or "shortcuts", but not both
Could you please help. Thank You
Here is my code:
myfolderSelectFunction() {
    final m = DirectoryPicker()..title = 'Select a directory';
    final result = m.getDirectory();
       FilesystemPicker(rootDirectory: result, fsType: FilesystemType.all, onSelect: (String value) {
         myFolderpath = value;
    });
    return myFolderpath;
  }


This is indicating FilesystemPicker requires either a rootDirectory or a list of shortcuts to be specified, but not both simultaneously. refer this as a Refer this link
to enable users to select and retrieve its path in your Flutter application, you can utilize the filesystem_picker package. for ex:
import 'package:filesystem_picker/filesystem_picker.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<String?> selectFolder(BuildContext context) async {
  // Obtain the root directory (ex., external storage dir)
  final Directory? rootDirectory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

  // if root dir not avalable
  if (rootDirectory == null) {
    return null;
  }

  // Open the filesystem picker
  return await FilesystemPicker.open(
    title: 'Select a Directory',
    context: context,
    rootDirectory: rootDirectory,
    fsType: FilesystemType.folder,
    pickText: 'Select this folder',
  );
}


hope this helps.

Happy coding, and best of luck with your projects! :)
